# Is Gravatar safe?

Tags: gravatar

I have just started a Gravatar acct. when I attempted to login using a secure socket to `www.gravatar.com` I was prompted with a warning that it was a different site, not the one I was after. I am using Chrome, so I do take it with a grain of salt, but the URL that I was told it actually was is an odd one: `gpl.wac.edgecastcdn.net`. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

It should be safe:

I believe *gpl.wac.edgecastcdn.net* is used for Gravatar content serving - the *cdn* is 'content delivery network'.

*edgecastcdn.net* resolves to a 404 and SiteAdvisor returns green (We tested this site and didn't find any significant problems.)

There are no online 'flags' or comments relating to Gravatar being unsafe.